# ComboBox.Item.add(USB1) switch language----- globalization - VS 2019 WPF

Tags: visual-studio, combobox, localization, addition, globalization

I added ComboBox from MainWindow_OnContentRendered, when I start the program, and how ComboBox.Item will find the resource file to change different language?> .How can I put WPF ComboBox content globalization.Thank you.

> hello.

```
A.
1.
public void MyComboBox()
{
 ComboBox.Item.add(USB1) 
ComboBox.Item.add(USB2) 
ComboBox.Item.add(USB3) 
}

2.
MainWindow_OnContentRendered  
{
MyComboBox();
}


     B.
    //ResourceHelper.cs           
    
         public static void LoadResource(string )  {
        var = (from d in _Resourcelist   where d.ToString().Equals()    select d).FirstOrDefault();                       
                               
        App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri(langType, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) });                                                        
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
       hread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question sounds quite simple but is quite difficult to answer. I've just started a new WPF application from scratch, so I thought about the issue of switching to a different language at runtime in general. Of course you have to set `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` like you do in your example. But what about the controls and their textual content?

My solution is a recursive method that I call with `MainWindow.Content` as parameter, and then it iterates deeper and deeper through the hierarchy of controls:

```
private static void ReloadAllText(object root)
{
    if (root is TextBlock textBlock1)
    {
        UpdateBinding(textBlock1, TextBlock.TextProperty);
    }
    else if (root is ContentControl contentControl)
    {
        if (contentControl.Content is string)
        {
            UpdateBinding(contentControl, ContentControl.ContentProperty);
        }
        else
        {
            ReloadAllText(contentControl.Content);
        }
    }
    else if (root is Panel panel)
    {
        foreach (var child in panel.Children)
        {
            ReloadAllText(child);
        }
    }
    else if (root is ItemsControl itemsControl)
    {
        for (int cnt = 0, cntMax = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(itemsControl); cnt < cntMax; cnt++)
        {
            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(itemsControl, cnt) is TextBlock textBlock2)
            {
                ReloadAllText(textBlock2);
            }
        }
        foreach (var item in itemsControl.Items)
        {
            ReloadAllText(item);
        }
    }
    else if (root is Decorator decorator)
    {
        ReloadAllText(decorator.Child);
    }
    else if (root is IRaiseLanguageChanged customItem)
    {
        customItem.RaiseLanguageChanged();
    }
}
```

The method consists of several branches:

- For `TextBlock` (which is also used by default as the text display element inside other, more complicated controls), the `Text` property is set to the new value. In my case, I just update the binding. In your case, the new text may have a different source, I don't know your architechture.
- For `ContentControl` (which is any control that has a `Content` property), it depends: If the content is just a string, I can set it to the new value right away. If it's more complex, then I have to recurse deeper.
- For `Panel` (which is the base class for `StackPanel`, `DockPanel`, `Grid` etc.), I just recurse for each child element.
- For `ItemsControl` **(so also for your `ComboBox`!)**, I recurse for each item. I added the `VisualTree` part only because I have a control template for an empty list box consisting of only a `TextBox` saying "no items". If you bind `ItemsSource` to an enum type, you must renew the `ItemsSourceProperty` binding.
- For `Decorator` (e.g. `Border`), I recurse for its single child.
- For custom/self-made controls, I have defined a custom interface `IRaiseLanguageChanged`, so they must implement a `RaiseLanguageChanged()` method and handle the language switch themselves. After all, a control itself knows best what to do when the language changes.
- This reflects only the set of controls I'm currently using. If you have additional control types, then you have to add respective branches. Please post them here, if you have any good ideas!